# pyspark giving error when trying to load cassandra

Tags: python, apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using pyspark to test out some sample code. Here is the pyspark shell command I am running

```
./bin/pyspark --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=172.28.0.162 --conf spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb=32 --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.4.0
```

When I run the following commands

```
import os
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="events", keyspace="sams").load().show()
```

I get this exception

```
Failed to load class for data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra
```

I can see the package present in the jar file or package that is downloaded. What is the issue?

This is the link I followed

```
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md
```

Comment: Spark version is 1.4

Comment: Cassandra version is 2.1.8

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Try erasing the package cache and running it again ... perhaps it's corruptted? The only other thing I could imagine is you built scala 2.11 spark ?

Comment: I removed the cache but it is still giving me the same error

Comment: Also the same command  works for ./bin/spark-shell but not for pyspark

Answer (score 0):

This happens to be a bug in spark 1.4
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8365